# mysql query getting cached

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a web page with a list of items and a form to add new items, and when you add an item, it updates the list.

Now the problem is when you add an item, it takes several minutes before the list on the page is updated, the item is inserted into the database correctly, and if I do the sql statement directly on the database, it returns the correct number of items.

Now the reason I am sure the data is cached somewhere, is that I got another page when I can see the list, and if I refresh it right after I add an item it shows correctly, and if I wait some time and refresh it shows correct again.

Also I have tried adding SQL_NO_CACHE to the query, but it did not change anything.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention I am doing the request with AJAX if it makes any difference.

I just tried to open the page in a different browser and it loads the same page, to clarify if I add an item i chrome, the new item does not show up in the list in Firefox.

Also I timed it takes close to 5 minutes flat for the page to show the correct list.

Comment: have you tried to `unset()` your variables?

Comment: This seems like an application issue, not a database issue.

Comment: Just checked, the list is cached across different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, my webhost use something called lightspeed which cache pages for faster loading, I have disabled it and every thing works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you instructing the browser to not cache your webpages?

Put this at the top of your listing page. The headers tell the browser to not cache the rendered HTML and to always request the most up to date information.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I tried that but it does not change anything, also I don't think it is a question about caching the page it self, since deleting cache/closing browser does not help either.